# Why am I getting a class cast exception if I have implemented comparator?

Tags: java, classcastexception, comparator, sortedset

Please have a look at this:

I have a sortedset:

```
SortedSet<Individual> individualSortedSet = new TreeSet<Individual>(new FitnessComparator());
```

This is the comparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FitnessComparator implements Comparator<Individual> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Individual individual1, Individual individual2) {
        if (individual1.getFitness() == individual2.getFitness())
            return 0;
        return (individual1.getFitness() > individual2.getFitness())? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

The Individual class is just a data class.

When I try to add ad element to the sortedset:

```
individualSortedSet.add(individual);
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Individual cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

I really dont understand why. I have looked at the following links but I cannot make it work..

[Why I'm not getting a class cast exception or some thing else when adding element to TreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001946/why-im-not-getting-a-class-cast-exception-or-some-thing-else-when-adding-elemen)

[List to TreeSet conversion produces: "java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504803/list-to-treeset-conversion-produces-java-lang-classcastexception-myclass-cann)

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception from?

Comment: @Kayaman according to his question - in `individualSortedSet.add(individual);`

Comment: By any chance, do you have some other `Individual` class getting mixed up here?

Comment: I just realised that I was using a different SortedSet and I didnt add the 'new FitnessComparator()'. Intellij changes it to <~> and I didnt catch that! Thank you! its fixed - looking at another bug now :-/

Comment: Sorry next time I will take a closer look at what line the exception is on..

Comment: YOu can simplyfy compare method : `return individual2.getFitness() - individual2.getFitness()`

Comment: Are you really sure, you have used `new TreeSet<Individual>(new FitnessComparator());` and there’s no `new TreeSet<Individual>()` (without the Comparator) involved?

Comment: @Holger yes that was the problem!

Comment: I think I need to start naming my variables alot more clearly but I find it hard to think of good names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a different sortedList in the code that was defined as follows:

```
SortedSet<Individual> individualSortedSet = new TreeSet<Individual>();
```

I didnt see that I have declared it again.. This is the correct declaration:

```
SortedSet<Individual> individualSortedSet = new TreeSet<Individual>(new FitnessComparator());
```